# How to run/test ECMAScript 3 JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, ecma, ecmascript-3

I am working on ExtendScript and it currently supports ECMAScript 3. Is there a way I can run or test some snippets in `ECMAScript 3` version engine?

I mean how can I check that the code I wrote is supported by `ECMAScript 3`?

Comment: There is no built–in functionality, so this is off–topic here as any resource is going to be off site. This is similar to a question asking for library or framework recommendations.

Comment: I mentioned `ExtendScript` just for reference. My question mainly is asking:  

how can I check that the code I wrote is supported by ECMAScript 3?

Comment: If it's just pure ECMAScript, you might be able to test in an old version of IE, say 6.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to download ExtendScript Toolkit from https://helpx.adobe.com/download-install/kb/creative-cloud-apps-download.html

If you want documentation, please refer to https://estk.aenhancers.com/